# Django: Get distinct values from a foreign key model

Tags: django, orm, view

Django newbie, so if this is super straightfoward I apologize.

I am attempting to get a listing of distinct "Name" values from a listing of "Activity"s for a given "Person".

Models setup as below

```
class Activity(models.Model):

Visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit)
Person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
Provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
ActivityType = models.ForeignKey(ActivityType)
Time_Spent = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
Repetitions = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
Weight_Resistance = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
Notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)


class ActivityType(models.Model):

Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Activity_Category = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=Activity_Category_Choices)
Location_Category = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices=Location_Category_Choices)
```

I can get a listing of all activities done with a given Person

```
person = Person.objects.get(id=person_id)
activity_list = person.activity_set.all()
```

I get a list of all activities for that person, no problem.

What I can't sort out is how to generate a list of distinct/unique Activity_Types found in person.activity_set.all()

```
person.activity_set.values('ActivityType').distinct()
```

only returns a dictionary with

```
{'ActivityType':<activitytype.id>}
```

I can't sort out how to get straight to the name attribute on ActivityType

This is pretty straightforward in plain ol' SQL, so I know my lack of groking the ORM is to blame.

Thanks.

Update: I have this working, sort of, but this CAN'T be the right way(tm) to do this..

```
distinct_activities = person.activity_set.values('ActivityType').distinct()
uniquelist = []
for x in distinct_activities:
    valuetofind = x['ActivityType']
    activitytype = ActivityType.objects.get(id=valuetofind)
    name = activitytype.Name
    uniquelist.append((valuetofind, name))
```

And then iterate over that uniquelist...

This has to be wrong...

Comment: from django documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Sorry, should have posted that I have tried that. The problem is that the ActivityType information isn't accessible via .distinct()... I can get the ids, but not the name. I just wondered if that was the wrong way to go down.

Answer (score 2):

```
unique_names = ActivityType.objects.filter(
    id__in=Activity.objects.filter(person=your_person).values_list('ActivityType__id', flat=True).distinct().values_list('Name', flat=True).distinct()
```

This should do the trick. There will be not a lot of db hits also.
Writing that down from my phone, so care for typos.